# Only keep first occurrence of duplicate column value if it has same value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I need to keep only the first occurrence of duplicate values in a column if they have the same value in another column. The other duplicates I need to replace with an empty string.  For instance, the text column saying,'how are you," should only display once because it has the same date as '2016-09-10' in the date column.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': ['2016-09-10', '2016-09-10',
                 '2016-09-10', '2016-09-10',
                 '2016-09-12', '2016-09-12',
                 '2016-09-13', '2016-09-13'],
        'text': ['hey how are you', 'hey how are you', 'hey how are you', 'good thanks',
                  'good thanks', 'good thanks', 'good thanks', 'good thanks']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The output is currently like this:

```
date           text
2016-09-10     hey how are you
2016-09-10     hey how are you
2016-09-10     hey how are you
2016-09-10     good thanks
2016-09-12     good thanks
```

My desired output is:

```
date           text
2016-09-10     hey how are you
2016-09-10     
2016-09-10     
2016-09-10     good thanks
2016-09-12     good thanks
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for set empty strings by condition:

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(['date','text']), 'text'] = ''

#if only 2 columns
#df.loc[df.duplicated(), 'text'] = ''
print (df)
         date             text
0  2016-09-10  hey how are you
1  2016-09-10                 
2  2016-09-10                 
3  2016-09-10      good thanks
4  2016-09-12      good thanks
5  2016-09-12                 
6  2016-09-13      good thanks
7  2016-09-13
```